# Matrix rank and linear independence of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

The following proposition is easy to verify:

Given $n$ functions $f_1,...,f_n$, they are linearly independent in an interval $I$ *if* there exists a set of $n$ points in $I$, namely $x_1,...,x_n$, such that the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(x_1) & \cdots & f_n(x_1) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f_1(x_n) & \cdots & f_n(x_n)
\end{pmatrix}

has full rank.

My question is: can I replace the *if* by *if and only if*? That is, if  $n$ functions are linearly independent, is it true that there exists a set of $n$ points such that the above matrix has full rank? I am pretty convinced so, but I am not being able to prove it.

Comment: [here's a proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146248/does-f1xf2y%e2%88%92f2xf1y-0-forall-x-y-in-mathbbr-mean-that-vectors-f/2146255#2146255) in the $n = 2$ case. I'd believe it in general...

Comment: @AlexSilva linear dependence already has a definition: functions are linearly dependent if there exists coefficients $c_i$ such that $\sum c_i f_i$ is the zero-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to prove this by contrapositive.  Define
$$
M(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \begin{pmatrix}
f_1(x_1) & \cdots & f_n(x_1) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f_1(x_n) & \cdots & f_n(x_n)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We have supposed, then, that for every collection $x_1,\dots,x_n$, the matrix $M$ fails to have full rank.  That is, there exists a function $g:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ such that
$$
M(x_1,\dots,x_n)g(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0
$$
We wish to conclude that $g$ may be taken to be a constant function.  Suppose for contradiction that it is impossible to do so.  That is, there exists a collection $\mathbf x^1,\dots,\mathbf x^m \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^m \ker M(\mathbf x^i) = \{0\}$.  Equivalently, the block matrix
$$
\tilde M = \pmatrix{M(\mathbf x^1) \\ \vdots \\ M(\mathbf x^n)}
$$
has full rank.  This means, however, that an $n \times n$ submatrix of $\tilde M$ has full rank.   However, this submatrix is necessarily of the form $M(\mathbf x^{i_1}_{k_{i_1}},\dots,\mathbf x^{i_n}_{k_{i_n}})$.  Thus, we  have contradicted the supposition that $M$ never has full rank.

Thus, there exists a constant $g = (c_1,\dots,c_n)$ such that $Mg = 0$.  In other words, 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i f_i(x) = 0
$$
for any $x \in \Bbb R$. That is, the functions $f_i$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: A subtle step here is the observation that it suffices to consider **finite** collections $\mathbf x^i$.  In order for this to work, it is important that we are considering the intersection of subspaces of a *finite dimensional* vector space.  I'd be happy to fill the details in there, assuming there are no other aspects of my proof that require explanation.

Comment: I am still trying to understand your proof, actually. I do not understand why $g$ has to be constant for the matrix $M$ to be singular. I would say that it suffices that $g$ is not the zero function... Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm saying that once we know $g$ may be constant, we can conclude that the $f_i$ are library dependent, as is done at the end of the proof

Comment: Yes, I do agree that if $g$ is non-zero and constant, then the $f_i$ are linearly dependent, contradicting the initial hypothesis. But how does that prove that there exists $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $M$ is non-singular? I mean, suppose there exists a function $g(x_1,...,x_n)$ that is zero nowhere and such that $Mg=0$ for all $x_1,...,x_n$. Then, $M$ is singular for every possible $x_1,...,x_n$. How do you prove that this implies that the $f_i$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: @D... I have a paragraph that starts "suppose for contradiction that it is impossible (to make $g$ constant)". Try to see where I go from there

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Please correct me if I am wrong:
1- you argue that if $M(x_1,...,x_n)$ is singular for any $x_1,...,x_n$ then there exists a non-zero function $g(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $Mg=0$  for all $x_1,...,x_n$.
2- you prove by contradiction that such $g$ would have to be a constant function.
3- you argue that, if $g$ is constant, then $f_1,...,f_n$ are linearly dependent, contradicting the initial hypothesis.

Is that right?

Comment: Correction: I prove that $g$ *necessarily can be* a constant function. Other than that, sounds right.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3516268/81360)

Comment: matrix rank, if *finite*, works in the same way for infinite matrices ( that is, the equality of row rank, column rank, and largest non-zero minor).