# Necessary Condition for linear independence of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove the following fact, which seems intuitive to me, yet I cannot find a way to show it.

Consider the set of functions $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$, $f_i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that this set is linearly independent, i.e.
$$\sum_i f_ic_i=0\implies c_i=0\;\;\; \forall i$$

Then there exists numbers $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    f_1(x_{1})       & f_2(x_{1})   & \dots & \dots & f_n(x_{1})  \\
    f_1(x_{2})       & \dots  & \dots  & \dots & \dots  \\
     \dots  & \dots  & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
    f_1(x_{n})        & \dots  & \dots  & \dots & f_n(x_{n})
\end{bmatrix}
has a nonzero determinat.

I have tried to reason by contraposition, assuming that the determinant vanishes for any choice of the $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Can you prove the $n=2$ case?  That could be easier and may given insight for the general case.

Comment: Note also that it is enough to show (for the $n=2$ case) that there exist $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that vectors $(f_1(x), f_1(y))$ and $(f_2(x), f_2(y))$ are linearly independent.  Similar for the general case.

Comment: [My post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2149041/81360) answers your question.  If you are satisfied with that, then I will go ahead and close this question.  If not, be sure to explain what it is that you don't understand from the post.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.